# How to automate chrome extension that interacts with the parent webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension, automated-tests, sikuli

I want to automate the testing for a chrome-extension.

I have used selenium-python to automate the parent web-page , but i am unable to use selenium to automate the chrome-extension because selenium is bound to the web-page view,so i am not able to click the chrome extension icon present in the title bar of the google chrome. Due to this limitation, i tried using sikuli to click on the chrome-extension icon ,but i couldn't get the DOM of the chrome-extension popup HTML that appear when the extension's icon is clicked, as i had to access the text displayed by the extension's pop up html page and then evaluated it.My test failed.

I thought i could use shift_to_window() but in vain,because its a pop up html, and hence i cant shift.If instead i use sikuli ,as the test cases increased , the amount of pictures needed to automate it will also increase, so it won't be feasible.

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OQgL.png),
In this picture,the web-store page is the parent page and the small popup in the right top corner,is the pop-up i am talking about, that appear after clicking the chrome extension . So basically i have to interact with that popup HTML.

Comment: i am using sikilu to click the chrome extension icon present in the menu bar of google chrome as its beyond the visibility of selenium.And i cant treat my pop up of that appears after clicking the chrome extension as an alert because i have to click  or send values to various elements inside the popup, but handling alert doesnt provide all these facilities.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand why you can't automate whatever webpage you have with Selenium and what is the limitation you are describing. Perhaps an example such as screenshot or even a link to the relevant webpage can help. Furthermore, I don't understand why do being unable to extract DOM from a page is a limitation while using Sikuli. Sikuli has nothing to gain from the DOM, it purely based on visual content of the screen.

I would attempt to handle the popup you are describing using using standard Selenium functionality so something like this:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

There are additional alert handling options so you can choose what suits you most.

Comment: my limitation is that i cant access the chrome-extension present in the menu bar of the google chrome browser. so i managed  to get it done using sikilu . then after the extension from the menu bar is clicked ... a pop up appears .. which is another html page ... so i want to basically interact with it .

Comment: @pk007 still not sure what popup you are referring to but if you want to get to any extension and interact with it, you can just navigate using selenium to "chrome://extensions/" from where you can access all the extensions.

Comment: Attached a screenshot for reference.And i can't access it as a separate page because it has to interact with the page that is currently opened. So i cant open it separately because using it's chrome extension id.